# Error in .net 4.5 expresiion expected

Tags: c#

this my code having the error expression expected. By the ninja trader  forum i got this is a 6.0 .net version in ninja script use 4.5 version. am using the 4.5 .net  still same error please Give me a solution.

```
        BuyLadderBrushDx?.Dispose(); BuyLadderBrushDx = null;
        SellLadderBrushDx?.Dispose(); SellLadderBrushDx = null;
        PositiveDeltaBrushDx?.Dispose(); PositiveDeltaBrushDx = null;
        NegativeDeltaBrushDx?.Dispose(); NegativeDeltaBrushDx = null;
        ChartBackgroundBrushDx?.Dispose(); ChartBackgroundBrushDx = null;
```

Comment: The safe navigation operator (?.) was introduced in C# 6.0, which is not the same thing as the .NET version number.

Answer (score 0):

The Elvis operator or Null-conditional operator (?.) was introduced in C# 6.0.
In your case it is the same as:

```
if(YourObject !== null){
    YourObject.Dispose();
}
```